# How is the salary for Data Scientist different among countries?

Tags: data

I would like to know the salary for Data Scientists by countries, but failed to find any resources on it.

I know that US gives data scientists an insanely high amoung of money (well, it might not be "insanely high" on the standard of US), but I rarely hear about any other countries, possibly except UK, Canada, and Australia in some cases.

Is there any research or survey or something that shows the diversity of salary for Data Scientists by countries, something like [for software engineers](http://swexperts.com/news/software-engineer-salaries-by-country/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest one I know is O'Reilly's survey [(here the last available from 2016)](http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/2016-data-science-salary-survey.csp). There are also polls on KDNuggets [(older version)](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2014/03/data-scientists-salary-survey-us-canada-australia-lead.html) and other websites. But, in general, most of them are not very representative.

You can also go look at the national averages on [glassdoor.com (example India)](https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/india-data-scientist-salary-SRCH_IL.0,5_IN115_KO6,20.htm) or other job sites.